# running a list through dplyr group_by and summarising & mutating each time

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to loop through a list and replace the group_by variable when using dplyr? Let me illustrate:

Lets say I have a list of variables from the dataset myData each of the variables has the same groups 1 through 10. Ideally I'd like to loop through the list and for each variable summarise and mutate the data as indicated below. Is this possible?

Here is a smaller generalized example but I just put the variable a in the group_by function but ideally i'd like to loop through a list and get that output for each variable.

```
vars <- list(a,b,c)

> myData
   success a b c
1        0 2 1 3
2        1 1 3 1
3        1 1 3 1
4        0 1 1 3
5        1 2 2 1
6        1 2 3 2
7        0 2 2 3
8        0 1 1 3
9        0 2 3 2
10       1 1 1 2
11       1 1 2 2
12       0 1 1 1
13       0 3 1 1
14       1 3 2 1

> myData %>% group_by(a) %>% 
+     summarise(success = sum(success), n = n()) %>% 
+     mutate(success_prop = success / sum(n))
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

  a success n success_prop
1 1       4 7   0.28571429
2 2       2 5   0.14285714
3 3       1 2   0.07142857
```

final results might look something like this:

```
group   a.success   a.n a.success_prop  b.success   b.n b.success_prop  c.success   c.n c.success_prop
1         4          7  0.28571429          1        6  0.07142857          4         6   0.2857143
2         2          5  0.14285714          3        4  0.21428571          3         4   0.2142857
3         1          2  0.07142857          3        4  0.21428571          0         4   0
```

Comment: Can you add `dput(myData)` to your post so that your example is reproducible?

Comment: I changed the question to have a more general example so it is reproducible

Comment: The first line of your desired output has `a.success = 4`, `a.n = 7`, and `a.success_prop = 0.28`. This seems inconsistent.

Comment: right I wanted the relative frequency

Comment: ahhh. I see. See my modified answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend converting your data in a [tidy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) format as a first step:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

tidy_data <- myData %>%
  gather(key, value, a:c)
```

It is then straightforward to use `group_by` and `summarise`.

**Edit**

```
tidy_data %>%
  group_by(key, value) %>%
  summarise(
    success = sum(success),
    n = n()
  ) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(
    success_prop = success / sum(n)
  )
```

Comment: This works as well but I think I like the solution that doesn't create another data.frame in memory

Comment: @moku - you can easily combine the two chains of operations if you wish. i just created the intermediate object to illustrate the format of `tidy_data`

Comment: True in that case I would assume it is to faster than lapply

Comment: This solution also put the data in a nice long format for graphing with ggplot so I think ultimately it had the most functionality and speed. Thanks alot @DMC